# Getting on error on select change function (unrecognized expression)

Tags: html, jquery

I have this code:

```
  $('select[name=picks[0][football]]').on('change', function() {
    alert( this.value );
  });
```

and here is the HTML

```
<select name="picks[0][football]">
                <option value="one">One</option>
                <option value="two">Two</option>
                <option value="three">Three</option>
              </select>
```

But when I run my code I get this error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
> select[name=picks[0][football]]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're missing quotes. `$('select[name="picks[0][football]"]')`

Comment: Yup you were right